# ASP.NET: Find which element had focus before postback?

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a series of controls on a page, including some textboxes that serve to record employee timesheet. When **OnTextChanged** fires, the page postback and update the overall working hours and minutes.

The problem is, when the user clicks the save button, a postback happens, but it is not because of ***save button***'s action but because OnTextChanged has fired. The user believes that the saving has gone well until he/she access the page again and doesn't find his/her data. It's next to the impossible to explain to user that they need to click twice because the first time the textbox loses focus and the second time it's the right one.

Is there a way to store the value of the last element that had the focus before the postback occured? I've tried to access the value of **__LASTFOCUS**, but I'm getting an empty string.

```
string lastFocus = Page.Request.Params.Get("__LASTFOCUS");
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You could slap an update panel bandaid on the textbox.

Comment: This is confusing: "when the user **clicks the save button**, a postback happens, but **it is not because of save button**'s action but because OnTextChanged has fired".

Comment: @TimSchmelter `OnTextChanged` causes a postback when the textbox loses focus. I think what he is describing is that the user types a number, then clicks `Save` and mistakes the `OnTextChanged` postback for the form submit postback.  edit - Unless I am not remembering how that event works correctly.

Comment: @asawyer: _"causes a postback when the textbox loses focus"_ No, only if you set `AutoPostBack="true"`. But i assume that it's `"false"` since it's triggered only if the user clicked the save-button.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah yes that's right. Well I would assume then that this is the situation then.  Richard77 would have to let us know.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, let's say a user worked 8 hours, so he enters 8 in the textbox. Then He clicks the save button to save his data. Now, the OnTextChanged is fired when the textbox loses focus. Which means, when the user clicks the save button, he transfers the focus from the textbox to the button. Thus, OnTextChanged fires before save button have the changed to do something.

Comment: @Richard77 Ok.... what are you doing in the textbox changed event autopostback that you can't do with the submit postback?

Comment: @asawyer, yes the autopostback is set to true to update the overall timsheet. In fact, user can enter many lines to describes what he did and a long he did it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to grab the last control that lost focus which has AutoPostBack="true", I believe you can get the Name of this control from `Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET")`.  This form variable contains the ID of any control invoking postback (in most, if not all, scenarios).

Comment: After the user enters the value to the textbox, he then clicks the save button. However, the textbox fires a OnTextChanged that causes the postback. __EVENTTARGET is giving me the name of the text. What I want is the name of the save button.

Comment: Why?  Why do you have AutoPostBack turned to on in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation with a GridView with an arbitrary amount of textboxes, each with AutoPostBack on and OnTextChanged event handlers. What I wanted to do was be able to tab out of a textbox, postback, then restore focus to the textbox that had focus before postback e.g. the textbox that I tabbed **to**.

This is what I ended up with:

```
function RestoreFocus(source, args) {
        var val = $("#<%=postbackFocusID.ClientID %>").attr("value");
        var el = document.getElementById(val);
        if (el != null)
            el.focus();
    }
    function PersistElementThatHasFocus(source, args) {
        $("#<%=postbackFocusID.ClientID %>").attr("value", document.activeElement.id);
    }
    function AddRequestHandler() {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(RestoreFocus);
        prm.add_beginRequest(PersistElementThatHasFocus);
    }
```

The postbackFocusID is just an asp:HiddenField.