# C# ASP.NET Set Focus On TextBox After Enter Key Triggers Save Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, focus

I have a ASP.NET 4.5 Page which has a dynamically created list of text boxes

I have set the default button for the asp.panel to be the Save button.

If the user is half way through filling out the text boxes and hits the enter key, the form saves, but then sets the focus back at the top of the page.  How can I have it set the focus back on the last text box that was being edited?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957036/asp-net-find-which-element-had-focus-before-postback

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm trying to do, I have no OnTextChanged Event.  Just an On Click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add onfocus handler to all form elements via javascript/jquery which will save the id of the currently focused control to hidden field and read that id value when with javascript on document load so you can set focus on the right control.

Example:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfFocusedControl" />
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
        var id = $('#hfFocusedControl').val()
        ;
        $('#'+id).focus();
        $('input').focus(saveIdOnFocus);


});
var saveIdOnFocus = function(e){
    var control = $(this)
        , id = control.attr('id')
    ;

    $('#hfFocusedControl').val(id);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert on JavaScript, so I could be implementing this incorrectly.  However it does not work as typed.  I created a variable test = hfFocusedControl.Value that runs only on post-back in the page load, and it always shows as ""

Comment: I take it back, this does work, I forgot that my master page caused this to be the incorrect ID for the hidden control, I had to view page source and grab the rendered ID.

Comment: @JStellato You can also use Client ID of the control like: $('#<%=hfFocusedControl.ClientID %>'). It may be neccessary to put whole <script> tag inside web control. It should work with (<asp:Panel runat="server"><script>...</script></asp:Panel>), still maybe even literal will suffice.